# Previous (business) dates pandas

Tags: pandas, date

I have a `pandas.core.series.Series` of specific dates (non-consecutive) which looks like the following:

```
0     1998-06-09
1     1998-08-07
2     1998-09-11
3     1998-10-13
4     1998-11-03
...   
231   2019-07-25
232   2019-09-12
233   2019-10-24
```

These dates are not necessarily business days. What I need is to create a list or series of dates which represent the previous day of the list that I have. In the new list, every previous day must be a business day, i.e. if (let's say) 1998-06-09 was a Monday, in the new list I should get 1998-06-05, i.e. the previous Friday. Any suggestions?

Comment: I mean you should get -06-06 right? 09 = Monday, 08= Sunday, 07= Saturday, 06 =Friday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`pd.offsets.BusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay.html)

When you consider a Business Day to be Monday - Friday

```
df['prev_bd'] = df['Date'] - pd.offsets.BusinessDay(n=1)
        Date    prev_bd
0 2012-12-20 2012-12-19
1 2012-12-21 2012-12-20
2 2012-12-22 2012-12-21
3 2012-12-23 2012-12-21
4 2012-12-24 2012-12-21
5 2012-12-25 2012-12-24
6 2012-12-26 2012-12-25
7 2012-12-27 2012-12-26
8 2012-12-28 2012-12-27
9 2012-12-29 2012-12-28
```

---

#### [pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html)

When you also want to skip holidays (or any set of dates in particular). Here we exclude Federal Holidays, though you can skip whatever dates you want by providing the appropriate calendar.

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
df['prev_nohol'] = df['Date'] - pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(n=1, calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
#PerformanceWarning

        Date    prev_bd prev_nohol
0 2012-12-20 2012-12-19 2012-12-19
1 2012-12-21 2012-12-20 2012-12-20
2 2012-12-22 2012-12-21 2012-12-21
3 2012-12-23 2012-12-21 2012-12-21
4 2012-12-24 2012-12-21 2012-12-21
5 2012-12-25 2012-12-24 2012-12-24
6 2012-12-26 2012-12-25 2012-12-24  # Christmas skipped because Federal Holiday
7 2012-12-27 2012-12-26 2012-12-26
8 2012-12-28 2012-12-27 2012-12-27
9 2012-12-29 2012-12-28 2012-12-28
```

---

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2012-12-20', periods=10, freq='D')})
```

Comment: Great solution. Worked exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @Matteo great! You might encounter performance warnings for some of these, but with these more custom offsets there often aren't ways around such things.

Comment: How would the command change if I wanted the previous day, now regardless being a business day?

Comment: @Matteo you could use `pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1)`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html. you could specify many normal offsets this way, like weeks or months, or years...